# how fix of the error about graphql codegen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js

When I do "yarn graphql-codegen" command
I got the following error...
I don't have an idea how to fix it.

```
% yarn graphql-codegen
yarn run v1.22.4
warning package.json: No license field
$ /Users/xxx/node_modules/.bin/graphql-codegen
✔ Parse Configuration
⚠ Generate outputs
  ❯ Generate to src/gql/
    ✖
      Failed to load schema from http://localhost:4000:
      connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4000
      Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
      GraphQL Code Generator supports:
      - ES Modules and CommonJS exports (export as default or named export "schema")
      - Introspection JSON File
      - URL of GraphQL endpoint
      - Multiple files with type definitions (glob expression)
      - String in config file
      Try to use one of above options and run codegen again.
    ◼ Load GraphQL documents
    ◼ Generate
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

did some commands like

```
yarn add @graphql-codegen/cli @graphql-codegen/typescript @graphql-codegen/typescript-operations
```

```
npm install --save-dev @graphql-codegen/cli @graphql-codegen/typescript @graphql-codegen/typescript-operations @graphql-codegen/client
```

/Users/xxx/node_modules/.bin/graphql-codegen

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const cli_js_1 = require("./cli.js");
const cli_error_js_1 = require("./utils/cli-error.js");
const [, , cmd] = process.argv;
(0, cli_js_1.runCli)(cmd)
    .then(returnCode => {
    process.exit(returnCode);
})
    .catch(error => {
    (0, cli_error_js_1.cliError)(error);
});
```

Comment: Do you have a GraphQL API host in `http://localhost:4000`?

Comment: I don't know.. where should I check it?

Answer (score 1):

It seemed like the host which you tried to connect to (`localhost:4000`) doesn't exist so `graphql-codegen` cant load the schema (per error log `Failed to load schema from http://localhost:4000:`)

Try to correct the host in your graphql-codegen config and run the command again.

Comment: thank you. I added graphql-codegen file but I don't know where I should edit...

Comment: You can read about the configuration here in the [docs](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/config-reference/codegen-config). I believe it is `schema`